# Computing Volume Using Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

The area of the base of the shape is enclosed by the functions $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $g(x)=x$, and whose cross-sections are squares.

I'm having trouble imagining what this looks like let alone computing its volume, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It depends in what direction you are considering the cross-sections. Planes parallel to the x-axis, or y-axis, or some other orientation?

Comment: Cross-section perpendicular to the x-axis

Comment: therefore it looks like you have an answer below

Answer (score 1):

The curves $f$ and $g$ intersect at $x=0$ and $x=1$. A cross-section of the solid taken perpendicular to the $x$ axis at some point $x$ will have side length $s$ where $s=x-\sqrt{x}$. Hence the area of this cross section will be $A(x)=s^2=(x-\sqrt{x})^2$. Thus the volume is 
$$
\int_{0}^1 A(x)\, dx=\int_{0}^1 (x-\sqrt{x})^2\, dx.
$$

Comment: Why is the side length $x-\sqrt{x}$? How was that determined?